# Toggle with text in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, text, toggle

I have tried to make an anchor change it's text when you click on it. But instead of toggling it just goes invisible and doesn't work.

here's the code:

```
$('a#button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    findListingBoxList.slideToggle('200');

    $(this).toggle(function() {
        $(this).html('Hide All');
    }, function() {
        $(this).html('Show All');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a id="button" href="#"></a>
<div id="ListingBox">

        <ul id="furniture">
            <li>Beds</li>
            <li>Chairs</li>
            <li>Tables</li>
            <li>Desks</li>
            <li>Shelves</li>
            <li>Cabinet</li>
            <li>Miscellaneous</li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="games">
            <li>PC</li>
            <li>Mac</li>
            <li>XBOX 360</li>
            <li>Playstation 3</li>
            <li>Nintendo Wii</li>
            <li>PS Vita</li>
            <li>Playstation 2</li>
            <li>Playstation</li>
            <li>Super Nintendo</li>
            <li>Nintendo DS</li>
            <li>Miscellaneous</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I have already tried it with `.html` and `.text`.

Comment: Share your HTML code also.

Comment: Where is `findListingBoxList` defined? This version of toggle is deprecated, and removed in 1.9 !

Comment: What version of jquery do you have?

Comment: Strike that, the [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) says deprecated, but does'nt look like it's removed, should still consider doing this another way.

Comment: I use the latest build of jQuery from the Google API.

Comment: @adeneo the var is defined just above the jquery code i wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toggle() event` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/) since 1.8

HTML :

```
<a href="#" id="button" class="hide_all">Hide ALL</a>

<div id="find">
  <p>Here is some content</p>
  <p>Here is some content</p>
</div>
```

JS :

```
var findListingBoxList = $('#find');

var labels = {
  hide: 'Hide ALL',
  show: 'Show ALL'
};

$('#button').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  if($(this).text() == labels.show) {
    $(this).text(labels.hide);
    findListingBoxList.slideDown();
  } else {
    $(this).text(labels.show);
    findListingBoxList.slideUp();
  }
})
```

Using slideDown/slideUp permit the link to work regardless its starting status (you could load the page with a Show ALL or a Hide ALL state.)

Look at this for a demo : http://codepen.io/ByScripts/pen/mbekK

Comment: No. `toggle()` runs a function on `mouseenter` and `mouseout` respectively.

Comment: My bad. Not the first I'm f*cked by the jQuery doc :/ And using the same method for two completly different behavior is a misconception to me... Nevertheless, the proposed solution is working. (and like said by @undefined, this method is deprecated... so the "-1" is not fair play ^^ )

Comment: The link provided doesn't work (perhaps a codepen problem); that said, you should put the gist of what works in the answer instead.

Comment: Right now the CodePen is working. And I updated it, using slideDown/slideUp instead of toggle. So it works well regardless the start status. Edit: I put the source code directly in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

`toggle` event method is deprecated, you can use `text` method callback function, note that by 200ms `slideToggle` is executed too fast.

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    findListingBoxList.slideToggle(600);   
    $(this).text(function(i, currentText){
       return currentText === 'Show All' ? 'Hide All' : 'Show All';
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried to copy paste this in there and work around with it but it didnt work though.

Comment: @user2021893 this worked for me if I used:  `$('#ListingBox ul').slideToggle(600);` so it must be your definition of findListingBoxList - whereever that is that is at fault here.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that you toggle event is removed in latest jquery and is deprecated from v 1.8.

Also, in your code you bind toggle event to your button only after it is clicked first time. Instead of that you should do something like this:

```
$('a#button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    findListingBoxList.slideToggle('200');

}).toggle(function() {
        $(this).html('Hide All');
    }, function() {
        $(this).html('Show All');
    });
```

And the last thing, it should be outside of `findListingBoxList`.

Answer (score 0):

```
findListingBoxList.slideToggle(200);
```

You have to give an integer argument not a string i.e. `'200'`